# Create a Run file in java

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Is there a way to create a "Runfile" in java which runs the program just by using a command `run`, like `Makefile` and `make`?
I am using linux and have to type this command very often `java -cp ../lib/*:../zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:. WordCount`. It would be convenient if there was a easier way!

Comment: @MadConan Thank you for sharing the link. Although I believe that talks about creating a jar file. But I am running my code in linux, and I just need to load and run the .class files. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a shell script name `run` and place  your required command.
Now make the `run` script executable -

```
chmod u+x run
```

Now you just execute the shell script from the terminal. If you need further improvement and if you are in `ubuntu` then you can create a `bin` directory at your home (~). Then you can place all of your commands in it. Generally your `~/.profile` file contains information about the `bin` directory at your home. Now the `bin` directory works as your private bin. If your `~/.profile` file doesn't contain any information about the `bin` directory then you can add the following line in your `~/.profile` -

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```