# Running script like regular command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat, ubuntu

I am using `ubuntu` 12.04. I have a custom script at my home directory, named ~/configure/run-server. Here -
**configure** - is directory at my home
**run-server** - is script at that runs tomcat and check some   constraint/prerequisite to run my project on tomcat. This script has no other dependency.The script is executable and runs fine without any errors.

To run the script I have to do -

```
$ ./configure/run-server
```

But I want to run the - `run-server` script like like regular command eg.- `cp`, `mv`, `scp` etc. To run these command we don't need to specify any other extra thing. How can I do this for the `run-server` command?

Thanks

Comment: Just put `$HOME/configure` in your PATH

Comment: Or you can just add an alias. 
`alias run-server "$HOME/configure/run-server"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in ubuntu this hack will work for you. I am not sure about the other linux distribution. Follow these steps -
**1.** Create a directory named bin at your home -

```
$ mkdir bin
```

**2.** Then place your `run-server` script to it.
**3.** Now look at your  ~/.profile file. This file contains information about the `bin` directory at your home. Now the `bin` directory works as your private `bin`. If your ~/.profile file doesn't contain any information about the `bin` directory then you can add the following line in your ~/.profile -

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Now you can use the script `run-server` like a regualar command only from your home.

If you want to get access the `run-server` command from all over your environment (ie.- from other user homes, or from any other places) place your `run-server` command to the /usr/bin directory. But I think the first one is the best option.

You may also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831397/create-a-run-file-in-java/29831465#29831465) this link.